# How to find a point which is outside a bunch of planes in 3D?

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, 3d

I would like to find an arbitrary $\mathbf{p} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ point which is not included in any of planes defined by surface normals $\mathbf{s}_1, \mathbf{s}_2,..., \mathbf{s}_m \in \mathbb{R}^3$ ($m \ge 1$ is a finite integer). All of these planes contain a given $\mathbf{p}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ point. Is there any chance to obtain the coordinates of such a $\mathbf{p}$ vector?

Comment: Choose a point at random.  It will be outside of all the planes with probability $1$.

Comment: A deterministic approach would be better for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the $z$ axis does not lie in any of the planes. Then find the points on that axis that are the intersections of the axis with the planes. Add $1$ to the largest $z$ coordinate to get a point (on the $z$ axis) on none of the planes.

If by (infinitesimal) chance the $z$ axis lies in one of the planes you can easily and deterministically find a line to use instead. One brute force way to do this is to choose $M$ vectors no triple of which are linearly dependent. None of your $m$ planes can contain more than two of these, so for large enough $M$ (you figure out how large) one of those lines will be in none of the planes. Use that one instead of the $z$ axis.

Comment: Thank you! Let me allow two questions: (1) What do you mean by "largest $z$ coordinate"? The largest z coordinate value of the "intersection" points (with sign)? (2) Could you please help me how to choose another line instead of the $z$ axis?

Comment: You can use absolute values or not, whichever you choose. The idea is just to find a point on the axis that's not one of the intersections. See my edit for a way to find a line if the $z$ axis doesn't work. It's ugly, but deterministic.

Comment: As far as I understand, $2m+1$ is a good choice for $M$ because $2m$ is the worst case of that each plane contains two different points of the $M$ ones. However, it is not clear for me that, for a fixed $M$, how can I select these vectors not triply dependent to each other?

Comment: @Mari Start with the three coordinate axes. Then when you need another, use the average value of any triple you already have.

Comment: Nice. A last note. Meanwhile it turned out that $\mathbf{p}$ should not be parallel to a given $\mathbf{q} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ ($\mathbf{q}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{p} \ne \pm 1$). Is it possible to take this condition into account in your suggested method?

Comment: @Mari Just check each possible $p$ as you come to it and skip it if it's parallel to $q$. Note: your condition for parallel works just for vectors of length $1$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{q}$ are preferably normalized.

Comment: Do you mean that after the line selection you described I should check for $p_z=z_\mathrm{max}+1,z_\mathrm{max}+2,...$ whether $\mathbf{p}$ is parallel to $\mathbf{q}$, where $z_\mathrm{max}$ is the largest $z$ coordinate of the intersection points?

Comment: @Mari Not quite. As you are generating new candidates for $p$ using triples of the ones you have so far, check that each isn't parallel to $q$. If it is, skip that one and move on to another triple.